# Как при нажатии `ctrl` + `левая кнопка мыши` открывать файл не в попапе, а в отдельной вкладке Vs Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

при нажатии `ctrl` + `левая кнопка мыши` и наведении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открывается **popup** этого файла[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Мне нужно чтобы всегда файл открывался в отдельной вкладке, как это сделать?**

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отключить Preview Mode, который устанавливается по дефолту. Для этого в настройках редактора у поля `workbench.editor.enablePreview` необходимо выставить значение `false` 

[Официальная документация](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_preview-mode) на этот счёт

Comment: Это не работает

Comment: @DmitriyBozhko вы переопределили enablePreview и проблема осталась?

Comment: Да, всё идентично, ничего не поменялось

Comment: @DmitriyBozhko за функционал описанный вами в условии отвечает режим "previewMode", других вариантов тут нет.